# Triple integral with absolute values in the domain

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the following integral:

$$ I = \int_T x z dx dy dz $$
With:
$$ T = \left\{ (x,y,z)\ {\Large\mid}\ \vert x - z \vert + \vert x - 2y \vert \leq \vert y \vert \leq 1 \right\} $$
I am struggling on picturing the set T, so the first I did was defining the following transformation:
$$ \phi(x,y,z) = (x-z,x-2y,y) = (u,v,w) $$
In this way, I have:
$$ A = \phi(T) = \{ (u,v,w) \vert \vert u \vert + \vert v \vert \leq \vert w \vert \leq 1\}$$
and then I need to calculate:
$$ I = \int_{A} (v+2w)*(v+2w-u)*\frac{1}{d_J}dudvdw $$
where $d_J$ is the determinant of the jacobian of the transformation $\phi$.
Still at this point I struggle to see a fast way to solve the integral after the transformation.
Does someone have a tip?

Comment: With your change of variables, the new domain is two right pyramids with square bases and a common apex at the origin. The integrals of $u v, v w, w u$ are zero due to symmetry. The triple integral of $4 w^2$ is a single integral of $4 w^2$ times the area of the square cross-section at height $w$ (and similarly for $v^2$ except the cross-sections are triangles). The side lengths of the squares (or triangles) depend on $w$ (or $v$) linearly. We get
$$I = 2 \int_0^1 4 w^2 (w \sqrt 2)^2 dw +
4 \int_0^1 v^2 \frac {(2 - 2 v) (1 - v)} 2 dv.$$

Comment: @Maxim How do you know that the domain A is made of two pyramids? Plus, why the integral of e.g $uv$ is 0 by symmetry?

Comment: Draw the region $|u| + |v| < |w|$ for a given $w$.

Answer (score 0):

$T = \{ (x,y,z) \vert \vert x - z \vert + \vert x - 2y \vert \leq \vert y \vert \leq 1 \}$

Here is how I am visualizing the region -

It is defined by set of $6$ planes,

i) $y = 1$

ii) $y = -1$

For $x \geq z, x \geq 2y, \,$ or $x \leq z, x \leq 2y, \,$ we have bounds as

iii) $2x-3y-z = 0$

iv) $2x-y-z = 0$

For $x \leq z, x \geq 2y, \,$ or $x \geq z, x \leq 2y, \,$ we have bounds as

v) $3y - z = 0$

vi) $y - z = 0$

Note the last $4$ planes pass through the origin at different angles and they are bound along y-axis by planes $y = 1, y = -1$.

So the region is split into two pyramids with vertex at $(0, 0, 0)$ and its base as a parallelogram (one pyramid above $XZ$ plane in first octant and one below it in eighth octant).

The parallelogram base is formed by intersection of $(i), (iii), (v); (i), (iii), (vi); (i), (iv), (v)$ and $(i), (iv), (vi)$ (length along $x$ axis is $1$, it goes from $x = 1$ to $2$ for $z = 1$ and from $x = 2$ to $3$ for $z = 3$.

Similar construct with $(ii)$ below $XZ$ plane.

Comment: Mmm, is there a more algebraic solution? I struggle to see this.